# Level 3 Fighter archer subclass suggestions? Homebrew allowed

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, homebrew, archetype

About to start a very combat and min/max heavy campaign that goes up to level 10.
I'm planning to go 7 levels of Revised Ranger [Homebrew Archer subclass](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dSrG-aJ-7qaIZgp0mjCPS5MZTFIxnv_4VaE_EQSqja0/edit?usp=sharing) and 3 levels fighter.
I'm looking for a relatively balanced fighter subclass that can increase my damage passively rather than a certain number of times per rest, so I'm looking for suggestions homebrew or otherwise. Keep in mind I'm only getting 3 levels in fighter.

Bonus question: Any homebrew or official race suggestions for an archer character with Tasha's custom origin?

I'm taking the sharpshooter feat as well.

Comment: Hey there Convergent, unfortunately, this sort of open ended question isn’t something we handle, see our [help article on questions to avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Fortunately, we maintain a [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where you may be able to generate some discussion.